# Group structure on the set of isomorphism classes of principal bundles

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, fiber-bundles, principal-bundles

Let $G$ be group (for simplicity --  abelian). The isomorphism classes of $G$-principal bundles over $X$ are classified by first cohomologies of certain sheaf on $X$ (e.g. $H^1(X, G)$,  if $G$ is discrete, or $H^1(\mathcal{O}_X)$ for holomorphic $U(1)$-bundles over complex manifolds etc.)

As one can take  sum of two cocycles, it gives us a structure of abelian group on the set of isomorphism classes of $G$-bundles. How to describe it explicitly? For example in case of $U(1)$-bundles it corresponds to tensor product of two line bundles. And what to do in more general case?

I guess, that one must take fibered product of two principal bundles $P_1 \times_X P_2$ and then take quotient over relation $(gp_1, p_2) \sim (p_1, gp_2)$. 
But I'm not sure if the construction is correct, and I would love to have some references in any case.

Comment: $G$ being abelian is not a simplifying assumption here; without it you have no group structure. Anyway, your guess is correct.

Comment: @V.Rogov It's well known that $H^1(X,G)$, when $G$ is abelian, has a group structure. Just show that under the identification of $G$-torsors and this cohomology group that your contracted product corresponds to the multiplication of cocycles. Then, you can just reference the well-known group structure of the cohomology group. I don't know of a single reference that actually writes this out explicitly--perhaps in Poonen's notes on rational points on varieties.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan  
Thank you! And do You have any ideas where to look up for any precise references? I've understood that this can be obtained from Eckmann-Hilton modulo some computations, which don't look sexy